# Create foursquare venue for real-time api

Tags: foursquare

I've created a consumer and managed to get a test running of the real-time api (user push).  How do I create and tie a venue to my consumer, so when users checkin at my venue, it will push to my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either [claim a venue](http://support.foursquare.com/entries/191119-how-do-i-claim-my-venue) you are managing, or you can create a home venue with your authenticated user. Then, you should automatically get a push notification for every checkin.

https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/realtime (see point "Venue Push API") says:

> The venue push API will push to your application every time a user checks in to a venue managed by any of your OAuth consumer's authorized users, or into a home venue that was created by one of your consumer's authorized users. This API is designed for applications whose users are managers of venues, allowing your application to get a real-time view of traffic into their venue, or for applications enabling foursquare-powered automation of a user's home.

Comment: I reclassified my venue as "home(private)" and managed to authorize my consumer/app with myself as the user but still can't get it to work.  I've got it sending test pushes from the consumer details page, but can't seem to get this linked up to my venue.

Comment: I authorized the app to my account using [this info]https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth). Furthermore, in the consumer details page, when I try to resend a push using the venue id it tells me "Your app can't see pushes from that venue"

Comment: What is your `Push API Notifications` setting for your consumer (https://de.foursquare.com/oauth/)?

Comment: Got it working. Looks like there was an issue with reclassifying a venue from "office" to "home".  Must work better if you just start out claiming it as a "home" venue.  That's what the guy at foursquare concluded.  He gave me ownership and set me up.  All is well now.